# JavaScript add an HTML class to div. If statement. Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

You may have seen the input box with success tick glythicon. [image]

I'm trying to make a form where the input box is normal (not green and no tick showing) and upon successful validation in JavaScript, I want it to change to to the green border and display the glythicon tick. I think that adding the class is the way to do it and I can't quite get it working.

I tried to use the following for adding a **class:**

```
document.getElementById('id').className.add('addditional classes');
```

But I can't figure out the correct syntax to get this code to work.

```
function validateName() {
     var name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;

     if(name.match(/^[A-Za-z]*\s{0}$/)){
            document.getElementById('firstcheck').classform-group, has-feedback.add(' has-success'); 
            document.getElementById('firstcheck2').classglythicon, glythicon-ok.add(' form-control-feedback');
     }
```

**HTML code**

```
<div id="firstcheck" class="form-group has-feedback">
     <input onblur="validateName()" id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
     <span id="firstcheck2" class="glyphicon glythicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always check your code carefully after copy+paste.

The placement of quotation marks is important, as is placement of dots

And this is jquery code:

```
$('id').addClass('addditional classes');
```

Try this instead:

```
function validateName() {
 var name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;

 if(name.match(/^[A-Za-z]*\s{0}$/)){
        document.getElementById('firstcheck').className += 'form-group has-feedback has-success'; 
        document.getElementById('firstcheck2').className += 'glythicon glythicon-ok form-control-feedback';
 }
```

Also dont include , in the classnames string

Comment: hmm I've just tried it but still not working, do you think there is anything else wrong perhaps in my code elsewhere that is preventing it

Comment: I updated within a min of answering, typo. Just noticed no edit flag if that quick

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the class this way:

```
//first get the element
var elem = document.getElementById("id");
//append new classes to your existing class
elem.className = elem.className + " additional classes";

//apply the same login in your remaining code
if(name.match(/^[A-Za-z]*\s{0}$/)){
        elem  = document.getElementById('firstcheck');
        elem.className = elem.className + " has-success";

        elem = document.getElementById('firstcheck2');
        elem.className = elem.className + " form-control-feedback"; 
 }
```

**OR**

You can easily achieve this with jquery like this:

```
$('id').addClass('additional-classes');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Bootstrap's JS needs jQuery you can make your life a bit easer here. I've created a small example https://jsfiddle.net/eg8dsgh2/. Just use jQuery's `addClass()`

Hope it helps

Comment: is there way to remove the classes when the backspace is pressed and then re-apply the validation function when it is not being pressed

Comment: you could call the validation function on every keypress `input.keydown(function(event) { validate(); })`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('firstcheck').classform-group, has-feedback.add(' has-success');
```

Is this invented? Where do you see something like this'
To add a class use className.

```
 document.querySelector('#firstcheck').className += " has-success";
```